# Looping result last index of array

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have the following code, to add each element an event using `addeventlistener`:

```
var x, y, z;

elm = elm.normalize();
if(!isobj(elm) && iselm(elm)) {
    elm = new Array(elm);
}

for(x in elm) {
    (function() {
        elm[x].addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert(x);
        });
    })();
}
```

but when I click any `element` that added an event by the loop it always show the last index `example`, like when I click the `element` it show an alert with `example` text inside the alert box.

Here was the result of `console.log(elm)` after `elm = elm.normalize()`:

> [sample: input.sample.fld, example: input.example.fld]

`isobj(elm)` is a `function` to check if `variable` is an `object`, same like
`iselm(elm)` is a `function` to check if `variable` is an `element`.

Due to fix this, I'm trying to use, `(function() { /* I put the addEventListener as above */ })();` inside the loop, but still not work.

I already make sure that `x` is always showing it index, but I didn't know why it always showing the last index in the event.

Please help.

Comment: You've *half*-applied one of the patterns that solves this problem, but only half of it. See the linked question's answers for details, but you need to pass `x` into your anonymous function inside the loop: `})(x);` rather than just `})();` (I use a different name for clarity, but many don't.) Separately: `for-in` is not how you loop through arrays; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446//9329476#9329476) for why and what to use instead (in this case, `forEach` would be particularly handy, as its callback would be the anonymous function).

Comment: thanks a lot, it's a new knowledge for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time that line of the code is executed, the for-loop has finished.

For explanation:https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value

You can use `let` if your browser supports it. (See article for explanation and alternatives)

```
var x, y, z;

elm = elm.normalize();
if(!isobj(elm) && iselm(elm)) {
    elm = new Array(elm);
}

for(x in elm) {
    (function() {
        let myX = x;
        elm[myX].addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert(myX);
        });
    })();

}
```

Comment: its not work, the last index is still showing in the event

Comment: `let myX = x` should be inside `(function() { /* code */ })();` thanks for your advice.

Comment: Don't declare `myX` as a parameter to the function passed to `addEventListener`. This will override the closure in the context of the function.

Comment: @RyanSearle Updated my answer

Comment: @CikIrvan Please accept the answer if this has solved it for you.

Comment: @RyanSearle your right

Comment: @RyanSearle i can't accept cause the answer is to fast to accept, but i already accept it.

Comment: @CikIrvan Not sure what you mean but it's right now.