# NodeJS variable scoping for loop problem, express/mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My Setup: NodeJS, express, mongoose

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    console.log("out: "+i);
    RegionData.findOne({'rid': results[i].region_id}, function (err, product) {
        if (product) {
            console.log("in: " + i);
        }
    });
}
```

The output:

```
out: 0
out: 1
out: 2
out: 3
in: 4
in: 4
in: 4
in: 4
```

My expect output:

```
out: 0
in: 0
out: 1
in: 1
out: 2
in: 2
out: 3
in: 3
```

I don't know why it is not my expect output, it finishes the "out: i" first then "in: i". Whether is the .findOne problem?

Comment: That `.findOne()` function is **asynchronous**. The value of `i` when those callbacks are finally invoked will be the value *after* the loop finishes.

Comment: If you write that with `.forEach()` instead of a `for` loop, you'll get the output you expect.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276979/looping-result-last-index-of-array/52277033#answer-52277033

Answer (score 1):

use closure:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        console.log("out: "+i);
        RegionData.findOne({'rid': results[i].region_id}, function (err, product) {
            if (product) {
                console.log("in: " + i);
            }
        });
    })(i)
}
```

or es6

```
for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
```

https://decembersoft.com/posts/understanding-javascript-closures-in-for-loops/

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` in your loop.  That way each iteration will get a unique value in the closure.

```
for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
```

Or use a `forEach`

```
results.forEach( (result, index) => { })
```

This snippet demonstrates both, and verifies that the `forEach` index is the same as the `let`.

```js
function getIt() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(Math.random())
    }, 1000)
  })
}

var i;
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log("out: " + i);
  getIt().then(product => {
    console.log("in: " + i);
  });
}

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
items.forEach((item, i) => {
  console.log("out2: " + i);
  getIt().then(product => {
    console.log("in2: " + i);
  });
})
```